# Dynamic categories to models

Tags: python, sql, django, database-design

everyone.
I have a problem in designing a small database. I have model Items and its categories. One item to one category only. 
The problem is that the some categories are parents for another category (like Tree View). 
[image]

So, my question is: how can I design my categories and items so that it will be easy to query and modify them.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt). It will make working with trees a lot easier. See the documentation.

```
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class Category(MPTTModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name="children")
    # other fields

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['title']

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='items')
    # other fields
```